# get identical column from dataframes of a list and assign to dataframes of another list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes, where all dataframes in the list have identical column names. For example, List A:

```
dfA1 <- data.frame(x1 = c("a", "b"), y1 = c(1, 2), z1 = c(10, 12))
dfA2 <- data.frame(x1 = c("c", "d"), y1 = c(3, 4), z1 = c(20, 22))
dfA3 <- data.frame(x1 = c("c", "d"), y1 = c(3, 4), z1 = c(30, 32))
dfA4 <- data.frame(x1 = c("e", "f"), y1 = c(5, 6), z1 = c(40, 42))

listA <- list(dfA1, dfA2, dfA3, dfA4)
```

I have another list of same number of dataframes which have same number of rows and an identical column. For example, ListB:

```
dfB1 <- data.frame(x1 = c("c", "d"))
dfB2 <- data.frame(x1 = c("a", "b"))
dfB3 <- data.frame(x1 = c("c", "d"))
dfB4 <- data.frame(x1 = c("e", "f"))

listB <- list(dfB1, dfB2, dfB3, dfB4)
```

I would like to take column y1 from dataframes of listA and add to the dataframes of listB based on column x1. How to do this?

Comment: Thank you. the given codes merge all column. But I need to add only 1 column from listA to listB. I have edited my example above and added a new column in listA.

Comment: I solved the problem differently. Now I would extract two columns (i.e. the common column and the new column to add into new list. Then I would merge the two lists. My new code is: `few.col <- lapply(listA, '[', c('x1', 'y1'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem differently. Now I would extract two columns (i.e. the common column and the new column to add into new list. Then I would merge the two lists. My new code is: `few.col <- lapply(listA, '[', c('x1', 'y1'))`